# Parameters from f:param not submitted with AJAX request when form enctype is multipart/form-data

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, wildfly

I'm running Wildfly 8.2 and I'm using the JSF version bundled with it, 2.2.8-jbossorg-1.

I have the following facelet:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:commandButton value="Submit">
        <f:param name="myparam" value="true"/>
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@this"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

When I press the submit button, several parameters are submitted, but not myparam. If I remove enctype="multipart/form-data" from the form, myparam=true is submitted just fine.

With or without enctype="multipart/form-data", if I remove f:ajax, myparam=true is always submitted.

Why is it working without enctype="multipart/form-data", but not with? And how can I get it to work?

Comment: Appears to be working in 2.2.11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Mojarra. I've just reported it as [issue 3968](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3968).

For now, one work around is to pass them as EL method arguments instead.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.action(true)}">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@this"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

```
public void action(boolean myparam) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good to know that it is a bug and thank you for reporting it. I just wish it had a better workaround. Method arguments doesn't work very well when the parameter value is dynamic. I may have to use 2.2.1, which appears to be the last version where this feature works.

Comment: I don't see how it would not work very well with "dynamic" values. Perhaps just a timing/scoping error as they are evaluated during apply request values phase of postback request instead of render response phase of initial request. This could indeed behave differently if the bean holding the "dynamic" values is request scoped.

Comment: It's definitely a problem I've encountered many times. But even so, the problem isn't limited to use of f:param in a h:commandButton. I've posted some of the code that actually caused me problems on issue 3968. It's from a custom component I call languageTabs, which is a bit like a dataTable, but instead of rendering a list, it renders a selection of languages. It also renders multiple command buttons to allow languages to be added and removed. It's ajax-enabled and makes it possible to have multi-language forms. [See it here](http://f.industry-supply.dk/stackoverflow/language-tabs.png)